# To Show only Last 7 days from Todays Date using jQuery UI Datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Can anyone please help, to show only last 7 days from Today's date with using jQuery UI Picker.

This is what I have so far.

```
function getMinDate(){ 
    var minDate = new Date(); //alert(minDate.getDate() - (7));    
    minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() - (7)); 
} 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#dt_store_visited_at").datepicker({ 
       "dateFormat": "dd-mm-yy", 
       "minDate": getMinDate(), 
       "maxDate": new Date() 
    }).attr("readonly", true); 
});
```

Comment: function getMinDate(){
 var minDate = new Date();
 //alert(minDate.getDate() - (7));
 minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() - (7));
}

$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#dt_store_visited_at").datepicker({
  "dateFormat": "dd-mm-yy",
  "minDate": getMinDate(),
  "maxDate": new Date()
 })
 .attr("readonly", true);
})

Comment: This might help http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#min-max

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get it Finally , Here is the code

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#dt_store_visited_at").datepicker({
        "dateFormat": "dd-mm-yy",
        "minDate": -7,
        "maxDate": new Date()
    })
    .attr("readonly", true);
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
minDate: new Date(Year, Month - 1, Day)
```

property

Answer (score 0):

```
var selectedDateDayNo = selectedDate.getDay();
        var daysDiff = selectedDateDayNo - weeekStartDayNo;

        var startDay = 0;

        if (daysDiff < 0) {
            // Previous week Need to be highlighted
            startDay = -(noOfDays + daysDiff);
        } else if (daysDiff > 0) {
            // Current week Need to be highlighted
            startDay = -daysDiff;
        }

        for ( var days = 0; days < noOfDays; days++) {
            var nextDayDate = new Date();
            nextDayDate.setDate(selectedDate.getDate() + startDay);
            startDay++;
            dates.push(nextDayDate);
        }
```

try using the above snippet . it work perfectly to me ... its based on the selected date .... Selection will be made from a predefined value(eg:"monday") by u or from the database .Hope this will help and also you have to add css to highlight the cells in DATEPICKER. all the best

Answer (score 0):

```
$( '#date' ).datepicker({
    minDate: '-7d',
    maxDate: new Date()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function getMinDate(){ 
    var minDate = new Date(); //
    minDate.setTime(minDate.getTime() - 7*24*60*60*1000);
                                        //^^^^^^^^^^^^^----miliseconds in 1 day
    return minDate;
}
```